# How to add 'custom' project templates in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

As the title says my question is how I can make a 'customizable' project template in WebStorm.

I don't mean like `Tools > Save Project as Template` but more like the default templates like Vue/Angular/React you name it where you can define/give arguments like a version of framework X/Y or different code blocks based on the given argument.

If there isn't a direct way to do this is there perhaps a way to do as such with plugins or is there an open issue/request for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, custom project templates can be added via plugins. See the related forum topics:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004365440-How-to-add-custom-project-template-to-intellij-plugin-
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206111059-Adding-a-project-template?page=1#community_comment_206674359
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206761085-Create-project-template-extensions-using-user-defined-templates#5529278
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206768385-create-a-new-project-type?page=1#community_comment_206128535).

See also [SDK docs](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html) for plugin creation guidelines.